# How to change a variable on the input text by hitting a button? React Native

Tags: react-native, button, textinput

The image is showing what the code does. I want the text inside the input Text to change when I hit the + or - button. How can I do that?

```
function Cerveja(props) {
const [count,setCount] = useState(0); 
 <View style={{flex: .1}}>
    <Button
        onPress={()=>setless(count*1)}
        title="-"
        color="#841584"
      />
  </View>
    <View style={{flex: 0.11}}>
    <TextInput     
      textAlign={'center'}
      style={{height: 40}}
      placeholder={'0'}
      onChangeText={(count) => setCount(count)}
      keyboardType={'numeric'}
    />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: .1}}>
      <Button 
          onPress={()=> setCount(count*1+1)}
          title="+"
          color="#841584"
      />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: .19}}>
      <Text textAlign={'center'}>R$ {parseFloat((count*1*props.price).toFixed(2))}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HyPv.jpg)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

this could work for the "+" button

```
onPress={()=> setCount(count+1)}
```

and this for the "-" button

```
onPress={()=> setCount(count-1)}
```

Comment: Sorry, the problem is not on the button, it is working fine changing the variable value. The point is that I would like it's value to be showen on the input text box

Comment: You have to use value={count} in the TextInput

Comment: yes, I tryed but it appear this warning: "Failed prop type: invalid prop 'value' of type 'number' expected 'string'.

Comment: try to pas it as a string using toString

Comment: I did value={count.toString()} and worked. THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I so happy that its working. sorry for caps, its to show that I'm happy :D